# Angular(2+) : Mutating an input param in child component

Tags: angular

Is mutating an input param in a child component fine or should all input objects be considered read-only & then emit event for any changes back to parent & delegate the change to parent component? Are there any problems that could arise out of modifying input params.

```
class ChildComponent {

  @Input() parentParam;
  @Output() clickValEvent = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  let parentParamClone = Object.assign({}, parentParam);

  childClickEvent(val) {
    //Update value locally.
    // parentParam.clickVal = val;

    //Inform parent & let it do necessary change.
    // this.clickValEvent.emit(val);

    //Only play with local clone.
    // parentParamClone.clickVal = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use inputs for input, and outputs for output.

Answer (score 5):

By right, yes, you can modify the `@input` value in child component, it will reflect in your parent component. But then there are 2 reasons you should avoid this:

1. it will not work for primitive value, if you expect to change `@input` primitive value and it reflect in your parent component, this will not work.
2. this is not a good practice, it open the chance for all the children component to arbitrary update the `@input` object and make us hard to trace the value changes. So using `@output` save us a lot of effort in future in maintaining the code, because it is more declarative.

I find it weird that, I couldn't find any official explanation regarding to this from Angular docs. Unlike `ReactJs` and `VueJs`, they very discourage us to mutate the `props` in child component.

Answer (score 0):

1. Passing your `@Input`as read-only is what I see most frequently,
   this way the parent's property stays imutable.
2. If make sense work if a copy of the `@Input` for you, it means you
   want to mutate the value only inside the child's component, and all
   changes will not affect the parent.
3. Using output when you have to change the object and persisting it in the parent component is the approach (that for me, is better), but i use to use two way binding instead of leading with the callback.

In your example, if you want a `@input` property where you change its value in the child's component and it mutate the father property, you should consider two way binding [`BANANA IN A BOX`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#two-way-binding---), so you code should look like this:

```
class ChildComponent {

  @Input() parentParam;
  @Output() parentParamChange = new EventEmitter<boolean>(); // <- this EventEmitter must have the parentParam type.

  let parentParamClone = Object.assign({}, parentParam);

  childClickEvent(val) {
    //Inform parent & let it do necessary change, when you
    // update the parent's value, it will be reflected in this component.
     this.parentParamChange.emit(val);
}
```

And you should use this way ni you html template:

```
...
[(parentParam)]="propertyYouArePassingHere"
...
```

instead of

```
...
    [parentParam]="propertyYouArePassingHere"
    (clickValEvent)="captureOutputCallback()" 
 ...
```

Note: To make it work you must have the output's name following this pattern: 
`inputThatYouWantMakeTwoWayBindName`+`Change`, that is the reason I renamed your output to `parentParamChange`.

Comment: My intent with question is to check what's the best way of doing this considering I have these 3 possibilities(code was just for a demo so can be flaky) & what are the trade-offs

Comment: In this case, you are passing a object to the child component, and objects are passing as reference, so when you do `parentParam.clickVal = val;` you are affecting the parent object as well.